# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploy app with docker compose up

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I run my spring-boot application locally with `docker compose up` command. As you see below `docker-compose.yml`, I don't need to pull an image of my application, it just builds via Dockerfile and deploys the container locally.

How can I achieve the same behavior on AWS Elasticbeanstalk? I checked several tutorials and all built the docker image and pushed a remote artifactory.

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: my_app 
   ... 
  app:
    depends_on:
      - my-db
    build: ../my_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
   ... 
          }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  db:
```

-- Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17

WORKDIR /my_app
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests

CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: Elastic beanstalk doesn't required docker. While creating app there you have to choose which environment to deploy your app like NodeJs, PHP etc. Everything will manage by Elastic beanstalk.

Comment: I will chose Docker environment.